# MVC4 - Creating a List of Model the View and passing to controller

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-4, post, view, controller

Move MVC blues. I'm trying to populate an empty List in the View and pass it to a controller. Here the model below

```
//Model
public class Person{
    string name {get;set;}
    int age {get;set;}
}
```

Here's the controller that I'd like to send the List to

```
//Controllers
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetPeople(List<Person> people) //Trying to get here
{
    foreach(var person in people)
    {
        //Do Work
    }
    ActionResult.Redirect(/Somewhere);
}
```

Here's the initial controller where my view is tied to that creates and passes an empty List

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var people = new List<People>();
    return View(people);
}
```

Here's the view. The point of confusion. I somehow need to use a form to add to the List then submit back to GetPeople controller

```
//Index View
@model List<People>  //This starts out empty;

<form method="POST" action="/Home/GetPeople">
<div name="person">
    <input name="name" />  
    <input name="age" />
</div>
<button> Add Another Person</button> //I'm thinking this would create another person div which would be added to the list to be passed to the controller someohow
<button> Submit </button> //Sends List<Person> to GetPeople controller
</form>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain names of the input fields on your view. To be posted as a member of a list, your fields should look like

```
<div>
    <input name="people[0].name" />  
    <input name="people[0].age" />
</div>
```

For the "Add Another Person" button you might need some javascript that will find out current index and insert fields with this index incremented. One thing to watch out is the "Remove" button you might want to have for new entries - make sure it does not creat gaps in indicies.

Comment: testing this out noww.. thanks +1 for the idea.. answer possibly

Comment: @Proximo, it should. Can you update the post with actual code?

Comment: It did.. thanks i changed it to <input name"[0].name" /> and it worked